# Uploaded a PDF but not visible on Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, contentversion

I uploaded a PDF to the ContentVersion object using dataloader. It uploaded successfully but when I click on it within SF it doesnt show anything. However if I download it I can see it.

Any reason why I can't see it within Salesforce?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337845&type=1),

Salesforce does not guarantee all file types and their contained features will properly generate previews in Content. The 'Previewing' section of the [Salesforce CRM Content documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_about.htm&type=5) outlines this limitation. [Viewing and Editing Content Details](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_preview.htm&language=en_US&type=5) mentions this limitation as well, and details which file types are currently supported for previewing.

Time to generate a file preview may be variable as the preview generation service is a shared resource as per [The Salesforce Platform Multitenant Architecture](https://architect.salesforce.com/fundamentals/platform-multitenant-architecture). It's not possible to guarantee that a file preview will be available within a specific time frame and longer than usual preview generation time is commonly attributed to temporary increases in resource utilization. These occurrences are frequently resolved naturally as the increased work loads are processed and return to normal levels. It's recommended to monitor and check with users to see if the condition may improve over time. However, if your org continually sees longer than typical preview rendition for an extended period of time, please note specific dates and times in order to log a case and ask Support to reference the internal information section of this article for review.

When a Content file is uploaded to Salesforce, the application generates PDF versions of the file's contents which are then used to generate an SVG version of the file for the online preview.

**This is not all inclusive, and the preview process is consistently being improved upon. So here is a list of Office and general file features that have been known to potentially cause issues in rendering Content previews.**

PowerPoint:

- Slide transitions.
- Animations.
- Embedded references to other files.
- Complex shapes containing gradients and several objects, like a dot
  graph for example.
- Smart Art - disable those features in your file.
- Avoid text areas with special formatting such as bullet points and
  custom spacing for example.
- Avoid using obscure fonts.
- Avoid using non-standard or custom page sizes.

PDF:

- Large numbers of pages. Exact number is dependent on their content
  but if the count is high (100+) it may cause the preview generation
  process to timeout.
- Note: The number of pages generally has more impact on preview
  generation than actual file size. Although the file may be under the
  recommended 25 MB limit, the process may not be able to generate a
  preview.
- A large number of shapes may cause the file to be too complex to
  render.
- Check boxes or interactive forms do not always render
  properly in preview mode.
- Scanned documents with multiple shading gradients and complex
  shapes.
- Dynamic/Interactive PDF such as XFA PDF cannot be previewed in All interfaces and thus is not supported. This type of file needs to be downloaded by you in order to view it properly.

Word:

- Embedded references to other files.
- Obscure fonts.
- Custom spacing, page sizes, margins.
- Bullets and multiple list levels.

Excel:

- Special formatting such as complex tables, embedded charts, and
  shading.
- Hidden columns or rows.
- Tables or cell formatting that extends beyond the data set
  unnecessarily. Formulas

TXT:

- Text or .txt files that are close to or larger than 524 KB will not
  generate previews.

General:

- Hyperlinks to URLs in all file types are unsupported, and generally
  will not be clickable within the file's preview.